# con un Select mostrar dos datos en labels con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

de antemano pido disculpas si me he saltado algo en como debo dirigirme a la comunidad, estoy dispuesto a seguir aprendiendo.
Bueno, me trae aquí una situación, estoy desarrollando en HTML, JS, Json intento que me muestre la información en mi html mediante un select, el Json trae también otros valores y dos de ellos necesito que me los muestre en 2 labels.

Este es mi código:

```js
let dataCombo = {};
function cargarSoftwareLicencia(){
    let urlFormAction = $("#url_ajax_edit").val();
    let jqxhr = $.post( urlFormAction, { getSoftwareLicencia: 1, action: "getSoftwareLicencia"})
        .done(function (data){
            data = JSON.parse( data);
            console.debug( data.data);
            /* console.log(data); */
            let impr1 = "";
            for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                console.debug(data.data[i]);
                console.log(data.data[i]);
                
                impr1 += "<option value=\""+data.data[i]['id_sofware']+"\">"+data.data[i]['serial']+"</option>\n";
                
                dataCombo[data.data[i]['id_sofware']] = data.data[i]['serial'];
                
            }
            $("#addSerial").html(impr1);
            
        })
        .fail(function(){
            console.log( "error" );
        });
```

```html
<span class="input-group-text " id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Serial</span>
<select type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" id="addSerial" name="serial"> </select>

<span class="input-group-text " id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Tipo</span>
<label type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" id="addTipo" name="tipo1" > </label>
                    
<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Versión</span>
<label type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby= "inputGroup-sizing-sm" id="addVersion" name="version1" > 
</label>
```

---

la información que trae desde el console.log(data.data[i]);

id_sofware: "4"

serial: "xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"

tipo: "Microsoft Office"

version: "2030 Professional super plus"

[[Prototype]]: Object

requiero capturar Tipo y versión.

les agradezco de antemano la ayuda que me puedan brindar. Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para aclarar cuál es exactamente el problema, porque no basta con _"dos de ellos necesito que me los muestre en 2 labels"_. Para poder tratar de ayudarte, necesitamos ver un ejemplo del JSON y saber qué elementos son los que quieres mostrar en cada etiqueta.

Comment: Triby, gracias por contestar, agrege la información que me envía JSON a la consola, si requieres algo más estoy atento, gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me da la impresión de que quieres usar el objeto `dataCombo` para obtener los valores que necesitas y ponerlos en las etiquetas que corresponden. Mi sugerencia es usar [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) en cada opción, los puedes recuperar fácilmente con [$(elemento).data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) y asignar el contenido con [$(elemento).html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Agrega una función que se ejecute cuando el `select` cambie de valor.

```js
let dataCombo = {};
function cargarSoftwareLicencia() {
    let urlFormAction = $("#url_ajax_edit").val();
    let jqxhr = $.post(
        urlFormAction,
        {
            getSoftwareLicencia: 1,
            action: "getSoftwareLicencia"
        }
    ).done(function (data){
        // Si vas a usar dataCombo, es conveniente vaciar contenido previo
        dataCombo = {};
        
        data = JSON.parse( data);
        let impr1 = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            // Agregar atributos de datos con tipo y versión
            impr1 += `<option value="${data.data[i]['id_sofware']}" data-tipo="${data.data[i]['tipo']}" data-version="${data.data[i]['version']}">${data.data[i]['serial']}</option>`;
            dataCombo[data.data[i]['id_sofware']] = data.data[i]['serial'];
        }
        $("#addSerial").html(impr1);
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log( "error" );
    });
}

// Agregar evento para cuando cambie valor del select
$('#addSerial').on('change', function() {
    // Obtener opción seleccionada
    let opt = $(this).find(':selected');
    // Obtener atributos de datos y asignar a cada etiqueta
    $('#addTipo').html($(opt).data('tipo'));
    $('#addVersion').html($(opt).data('version'));
});
```

```css
select, label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="input-group-text " id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Serial</span>
<select type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" id="addSerial" name="serial">
    <option disabled selected>-- Selecciona --</option>
    <option value="1" data-tipo="Microsoft Office 1" data-version="365">365-365-365</option>
    <option value="2" data-tipo="Microsoft Office 2" data-version="2016">016-016-016</option>
    <option value="3" data-tipo="Microsoft Office 3" data-version="2013">013-013-013</option>
    <option value="4" data-tipo="Microsoft Office 4" data-version="2010">010-010-010</option>
</select>

<span class="input-group-text " id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Tipo</span>
<label type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" id="addTipo" name="tipo1" > </label>
                    
<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Versión</span>
<label type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby= "inputGroup-sizing-sm" id="addVersion" name="version1" > 
</label>
```

Puse el ejemplo con las opciones directamente en HTML, pero no debes tener problema al ejecutarlo por AJAX y, para mejor experiencia de uso, hay una opción deshabilitada y seleccionada por defecto y los datos aparecerán solo cuando selecciones una opción válida. Quizá convendría agregarlo también al cargar los datos por AJAX.

Comment: Gracias Triby, es básicamente lo que necesitaba. gracias!